# Adding a vectorSource to a directorySource in tm

Tags: r, csv, tm

I am absolutely new to R (bear with me), but I need to utilize it for academic work. I am using RStudio Version 1.0.136 for this. I am using the tm package to perform text transformations. Within the package, there are ways to identify a source, eg:

```
> getSources()
[1] "DataframeSource" "DirSource"       "URISource"       "VectorSource"     "XMLSource"       "ZipSourc
```

I am also using the basic tutorial for text mining called Basic Text Mining in R. In this tutorial, it uses the DirSource to get a group of text data files from a folder, eg (and in my case):

```
> cname <- file.path("C:", "texts")   
> cname
[1] "C:/texts"
> dir(cname)
 [1] "Feb24.csv"        "Feb25.csv"        "Feb26.csv"        "Feb27 Day OF.csv" "Feb28.csv"       
 [6] "Mar1.csv"         "Mar2.csv"         "Mar3.csv"         "Mar4.csv"         "Mar5.csv"        
[11] "Mar6.csv"        
> library(tm) 
> library(NLP)
> docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname))   
> summary(docs)
                 Length Class             Mode
Feb24.csv        2      PlainTextDocument list
Feb25.csv        2      PlainTextDocument list
Feb26.csv        2      PlainTextDocument list
Feb27 Day OF.csv 2      PlainTextDocument list
Feb28.csv        2      PlainTextDocument list
Mar1.csv         2      PlainTextDocument list
Mar2.csv         2      PlainTextDocument list
Mar3.csv         2      PlainTextDocument list
Mar4.csv         2      PlainTextDocument list
Mar5.csv         2      PlainTextDocument list
Mar6.csv         2      PlainTextDocument list
```

This works, but not very well in that all the data in the csv files are then processed. I want to specify just the text column for processing. I can get it done with:

```
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(feb24.csv$text))
```

But this means I have do it one at a time for each of the 11 csv files which wastes time. If you are still with me at this point, I am trying to find out how to make a VectorSource work in conjunction with that dirSource. Or if there is a way to better automate this process. I need to keep these 11 files separate for now as well, but they all need their text columns to be processed. Hopefully I have described what I am trying to do here well enough. Again, very new to this. Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: What is in the csv files? is there a column and then text or only the text?

Comment: Each csv has columns of username, date, retweets, favorites, text, geo, mentions, hashtags, id, and permalink. I want to keep all the data in those respective columns intact except for the text columns, which will be processed.